# Android: Can anyone guide me to add the tips and photos to foursquare using the android application?

Tags: android, api, foursquare

i am integrating foursquare app in my android app. In this i have to add the tips and photo's with the checking option. please any one give me suggestions in making code.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the foursquare API is available at http://developer.foursquare.com. There you can find the documentation for how to access tips, photos, and check-ins.

Comment: k. Thank u. i got idea to add photo and tip